# Check if a property of an Entity is marked as IsRequired() via reflections and EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, system.reflection

**THE QUESTION**

If I have an array of properties of a certain Entity and I'm iterating through them, **is there any way to check if the reflected type property that I am iterating in each cycle is configured as `.IsRequired()`** on its corresponding Entity?

**EXAMPLE**

This question has to be intended especially for `string` properties, as in most of value types, if a db property allows `null` values, then it is mapped by EF Core's Scaffolding operation as nullable type.

E.G.: a nullable int is mapped as `int?`, while a not-nullable one is mapped as `int`.

If I iterate through that mapped Entity's properties, to check if that property I am iterating now is a nullable one, I just have to check if `myproperty.PropertyType == typeof(int?)` but...what in case of a `string` type?

Is there any way to check if it's marked as an `.IsRequired()` property?

**MY CODE SO FAR**

In my code I have the following function, which is supposed to receive as params:

- `objectInstance`: a Proxy derived from the Entity that I have to update, that I (have to) find previously
- `values`: a dictionary with the property name and the new value of the properties I have to update. It could be filled with every property, or just with some of them.
- `properties`: the array of properties of the class I previously found via reflections

This function is supposed to iterate through the properties array and for each property, if the new value is contained inside the dictionary, to set its new value on the instance of the class.

```
private static bool SetValues(Object objectInstance, Dictionary<string, object> values, PropertyInfo[] properties)
{
    bool edited = false;
    foreach (var item in values)
    {
        var temp = properties.Where(w => w.Name.ToLower() == item.Key.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
        if (temp != null)
        {
            edited = true;
            if (temp.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                //here it is where I would like to do the above mentioned check
                temp.SetValue(objectInstance, Convert.ToString(item.Value));
            }
            if (temp.PropertyType == typeof(int) || temp.PropertyType == typeof(int?))
            {
                temp.SetValue(objectInstance, Convert.ToInt32(item.Value));
            }
            if (temp.PropertyType == typeof(long) || temp.PropertyType == typeof(long?))
            {
                temp.SetValue(objectInstance, Convert.ToInt64(item.Value));
            }
            if (temp.PropertyType == typeof(decimal) || temp.PropertyType == typeof(decimal?))
            {
                temp.SetValue(objectInstance, Convert.ToDecimal(item.Value));
            }
            if (temp.PropertyType == typeof(bool) || temp.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
            {
                temp.SetValue(objectInstance, Convert.ToBoolean(item.Value));
            }
            if (temp.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || temp.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                temp.SetValue(objectInstance, Convert.ToDateTime(item.Value));
            }
        }
    }
    return edited;
}
```

Here's how I get "objectInstance":

```
var objectInstance = _context.Query(TableType).Where("Id = @0", rowKey).FirstOrDefault();
```

Where "Query" is an Extension:

```
public static IQueryable Query(this DbContext context, Type entityType) =>
            (IQueryable)((IDbSetCache)context).GetOrAddSet(context.GetDependencies().SetSource, entityType);
```

And... an example of what I mean with a `IsRequired()`-marked property of an Entity, to avoid misunderstandings:

```
 public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyTable> builder)
 {
    //[a lot of properties above here...]
    builder.Property(e => e.Code)
                    .IsRequired()  //that's it!
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
    //...
 }
```

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO ACHIEVE**

On the `//here it is where I would like to do the above mentioned check` comment's position, I would like to check if (pseudocode):

```
if(temp.IsRequired())
{
   if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(item.Value)))
   {
       temp.SetValue(objectInstance, "");
   }
   else
   {
       temp.SetValue(objectInstance, Convert.ToString(item.Value));
   }
}
else
{
   if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(item.Value)))
   {
       temp.SetValue(objectInstance, null);
   }
   else
   {
       temp.SetValue(objectInstance, Convert.ToString(item.Value));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper way of doing that in EF Core is not using reflection, but the EF Core provided metadata. Which means your method should have access (receive as argument) the `DbContext` (or at least [IModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imodel?view=efcore-2.1) returned by [DbContext.Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.model?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Model) property).

Once you have it, you could use [FindEntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelextensions.findentitytype?view=efcore-2.1) method to get the [IEntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ientitytype?view=efcore-2.1) containing the associated metadata with the entity class, then some of the [FindProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ientitytype.findproperty?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IEntityType_FindProperty_System_String_) method overloads to get the [IProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iproperty?view=efcore-2.1) containing the metadata associated with that property, and finally check the [IsNullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iproperty?view=efcore-2.1) property:

> Gets a value indicating whether this property can contain null.

which correctly takes into account both data type, data annotations and fluent configuration.

Something like this:

```
private static bool SetValues(DbContext db, Object objectInstance, 
    Dictionary<string, object> values, PropertyInfo[] properties)
{
    var entityType = db.Model.FindEntityType(objectInstance.GetType());
    bool edited = false;
    foreach (var item in values)
    {
        var property = entityType.FindProperty(item.Key);
        if (property != null)
        {
            var propertyType = property.ClrType;
            bool isRequired = !property.IsNullable;
            // do something ...     
        }
    }
}
```

This eliminates the need `PropertyInfo[] properties` parameter.

**Update:** In order to work with proxy classes, instead of `FindEntityType` use the [FindRuntimeEntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelextensions.findruntimeentitytype?view=efcore-2.1) method.

> Gets the entity that maps the given entity class, where the class may be a proxy derived from the actual entity type. Returns null if no entity type with the given CLR type is found or the entity type has a defining navigation.

Comment: Seems good! How about the `temp.SetValue(objectInstance, item.Value);`? How does it change in this new version of `SetValues`?

Comment: @Deadpool  `property.PropertyInfo.SetValue(objectInstance, item.Value);`

Comment: Ok i tried but `db.Model.FindEntityType(objectInstance.GetType())` returns null, while `objectInstance.GetType()` returns the correct equivalent Entity Proxy. What could this issue be caused from?

Comment: So the `entityInstance` is a proxy?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I didn't mention it before (I thought it wasn't quite relevant but it seems I was wrong)... Is there any adaptation to the function you mentioned that I can do in order to make it work with proxies? PS: I added to the OP the way I get the Proxy

Comment: Well, it works! You literally saved my day! Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should do like this

```
 [IsNotNullable]
    [IsPK]
    [IsIdentity]
    [SequenceNameAttribute("Id")]
    [Required]
    public Int32 Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id;
        }
        set
        {
            _Id = value;
        }
    }
var t = typeof(YourClass);
var pi = t.GetProperty("Id");
var attr = (Required[])pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Required), false);
if (attr.Length > 0) {
    // Use attr[0], you'll need foreach on attr if MultiUse is true
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Forgive me for my ignorance but, does it works also if `IsRequired`/`Required` is not defined within a square-brackets attribute like in your answer's example (`[Required]`) but it's defined as my example above(on the bottom of the question)?

Comment: Yes. With "IsRequired" you can check the presence of "Required" decorator.

Comment: It gives me an error since "Require" does not exists and I can't figure out from where I have to import it... I suppose it's a custom attribute that you suggest me to create and put manually above required properties, isn't it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? That decorator is given from EF (if you set to "not nullable" that property on the DB).

Comment: Mhh... I am using Entity Framework Core, I guess it could be different between EF and EF Core... or are you using EF Core too?

Comment: Is the same thing https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/ef/core/modeling/required-optional

Comment: Yeah, just checked and it exists but for some reason I just can use it on the Entity class but not on a Controller... And the function is inside a Controller. Adding `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` on the Entity works fine, but adding to the controller where the function is located does not work... Instead, it finds me the `Required` inside `Newtonsoft.Json.Required`

Comment: That is your only problem. Check also this link http://johnatten.com/2014/03/10/c-using-reflection-and-custom-attributes-to-map-object-properties/

Comment: I solved by using Ivan Stoev's solution, by the way thanks! Givin' a +1 since also yours makes sense, I'm not accepting as answer because it didn't work for me (but it looked more like some library missing), but if it works for you maybe i hope it could work also for someone else! By the way, thanks!